# In safari on button click my page flickering and going to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using html video in page background.whenever click on start button I need to redirect page to different url.for that in button click i am using window.loaction.href. In safari whenever click on button its flickering and stopping the video a second and then redirecting.How to avoid this?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing some code.

Comment: Above all window.loaction.href. is not a Angular way to redirect.

Comment: This seems natural behaviour of the browser as so much `repaint` work is happening. Suggestion: `stop` the video + `fade-out` the screen -> redirect